# Optional argument for each positional argument

Tags: python, argparse

Using argparse (or something else?) I would like each positional argument to have an optional argument with default value.

The arguments would be as so:

```
script.py arg1 arg2 -o 1 arg3 -o 2 arg4 arg5
```

and I want it to parse this into something usable, like a list of the positional arguments and a list of the optional arguments *with defaults filled in*.  e.g. if the default for the optional is 0 in the example above:

```
positional = [arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5]
optional = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0]
```

in other words, `parser.add_argument('-o', action='append')` is not what I want because I lose the positional argument, each optional argument is associated to.

Comment: Do you know how many positional arguments you'll have?

Comment: No. I want to loop over the arguments regardless of how many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple hack that I put together that might be a reasonable place to start:

```
import argparse

class PositionalAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self,parser,namespace,values,option_string=None):
        lst = getattr(namespace,self.dest)
        lst.append(values)
        parser.last_positional_values = lst
        all_positional = getattr(namespace,'all_positional',[])
        all_positional.append(lst)
        namespace.all_positional = all_positional

class AssociateAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self,parser,namespace,values,option_string=None):
        try:
            parser.last_positional_values.append(values)
        except AttributeError:
            pass

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-o',action=AssociateAction,dest=argparse.SUPPRESS)
junk,unknown = parser.parse_known_args()

for i,_ in enumerate(unknown):
    parser.add_argument('arg%d'%i,action=PositionalAction,default=[])

print parser.parse_args()
```

And here it is in action:

```
temp $ python test1.py foo -o 1 bar -o 2 baz qux -o 4
Namespace(all_positional=[['foo', '1'], ['bar', '2'], ['baz'], ['qux', '4']], arg0=['foo', '1'], arg1=['bar', '2'], arg2=['baz'], arg3=['qux', '4'])
```

This problem has a few challenges.  First, You want to accept an arbitrary number of positional arguments -- argparse doesn't like that.  argparse wants to know up front what to expect.  The solution is to build a parser and parse the commandline, but to tell argparse to only parse the known arguments only (in this case, the non-positional `-o` arguments are all parsed silently but the "positional" arguments aren't parsed.).  `parse_known_args` is perfect for this as it returns a tuple in the form `(namespace_of_parsed_stuff, uknown_args)`.  So now we know the unknown arguments -- We just need to add a positional argument to the parser for each one to make parse_args happy.

Now, what are the custom actions actually doing?  When a positional argument is found (on the second pass), we get the default (which is a list) and add the value to that list (hereafter I'll call it the "value" list).  We then modify the *parser* with a reference to the "value" list.  We also get the "all_positional" list from the namespace.  If it doesn't have that attribute, we just get an empty list.  We add the "value" list to the "all_positional" list and put it back on the namespace.

Now, when we hit a `-o` flag, we look at the parser to get the "value" list and we add the additional value to that list.  We could do the same thing without touching the parser at all ... (we could look at `namespace.all_positional[-1]` -- It's the same list as `parser.last_positional_values`).

Comment: This magic you have produced seems to do what I want (or close enough), but it'll take me a while to fully understand what you've done.  Regardless, thank you!

Comment: I'll add a few comments about what is going on to hopefully help it be more understandable.

Comment: Don't worry, the misunderstandings certainly have more to do with my lack of expertise than any lack of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply stepping through the sys.argv yourself.  You don't seem to need the extra features that argparse offers.  For example:

```
argv='script.py arg1 arg2 -o 1 arg3 -o 2 arg4 arg5'.split()
pos=[]
opt=[]
i=1
while i<len(argv):
    a=argv[i]
    if a[:2]!='-o':
        pos.append(a)
        opt.append(0)
    else:
        i += 1
        opt[-1]=argv[i]
    i += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `optparse`, it's powerful if a tiny bit complicated:

```
op = optparse.OptionParser(usage=usage)

op.add_option('-c','--cmd',dest='cmd',help="""Command to run. Mutually exclusive with -s. You can use string ${ADDR} to have it replaced with specified host address in the command. """)

op.add_option('-s','--script',dest='script',help="""Script file to run remotely. Mutually exclusive with -c. A script can have its own arguments; specify the whole command in doublequotes, like "script -arg arg".""")

op.add_option('-l','--replicate-owner',dest='replicateowner',action="store_true",help="""Replicate (symbolic) owner and (symbolic) group of the file on the remote host, if possible. If remote account with username the same as local account does not exist on remote host, this will silently fail.""")

# parse cmdline options
(opts, args) = op.parse_args()
```

opts gets you named args and args gets you positional args.

You can have positional arguments taking values or setting true or false and more IIRC.

Comment: This doesn't answer the specific question. The poster seems aware of how to use {opt,arg}parse in general.